# Robot events not firing up when calling from visual c++ code

Tags: java, visual-c++, awtrobot

I have a project of screen sharing between 2 users and then remote controlling the screen.I have a visual c++ code through which i am calling the Java screen share method to share the screen.That is working very much fine.

Now i am trying to call the other robot events like (mouseMove,keypress etc).I am able to call the Java methods(which contains robot events calls) from my c++ code smoothly and the function is always returning true back to my c++ code,thereby showing successfull execution,but the robot events written in the Java methods is not getting Fired.Can anyone help me to get in the proper direction.My code is as below:

From c++ code:

```
 status=  m_pJVM->InvokeClassMethod(m_sccObj,"keyPress", 
                                "(D)V", NULL,
                                 keyCode);
   if (status)
    {
      GetLogger()->Log(_T("Successfull key Press"));
   }
    else
    {
      GetLogger()->Log(_T("Unsuccessfull key Press"));
    }
```

Here i am always getting "Successfull key press" as the output on my console.

In Java side the code is :

```
public boolean keyPress(double key)
    {
        try
        {
            this.robot = new Robot();
            if(robot != null)
            {
            robot.delay(5000);
            robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_T);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
            return true;
            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell whether i am missing anythng here.

Thanks,
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The java process should be running in a user space that has access to the `current desktop`.
 Check under what credentials it starts. If its running via a service- make sure:

`Services.msc` > `[Your host service]` > `Log On` > `Allow service to interact with desktop` 
is checked.

Though since you say its able to access screen already - this may **not** be the issue.

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal for the fast reply,but as u suggested this might not be the issue.I created test app and then called robot events ,it worked like charm.seems their is some issue while calling from c++ code

Comment: how about you change the KeyPress return type and value to check what is the code flow: change return type to `Integer` and return say 99 on success and 11 on failure. Also i see no use of the input param `key` to the `KeyPress` java fn.

Comment: Hi Ujjawal,yes test app was in java.And also i returned int value from java method and i always got 1 for success as return value

Comment: There is an use of input param,right now i havent used it,i was checking the robot working.